# XSLT match outputs value from outside the matched template

Tags: xml, xslt

Why does xsl:template match output values from nodes that have not been referred to in the xslt?
To understand what was happening, I removed all my code from within the xslt, and see an output with all node values? why is this? I was hoping the output xsl should contain values of only those node which have been explicitly mapped in the xslt
Here is an example.
This is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

And this is the xslt I'm using to see why node values are in the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I have no template match to transform any data from the XML.
Following is the output I got:

Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.90 1985 Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler UK CBS Records 9.90 1988 Greatest Hits Dolly Parton USA RCA 9.90 1982 Still got the blues Gary Moore UK Virgin records 10.20 1990 Eros Eros Ramazzotti EU BMG 9.90 1997 One night only Bee Gees UK Polydor 10.90 1998 Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook UK CBS 8.10 1973 Maggie May Rod Stewart UK Pickwick 8.50 1990

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for what you see are the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule).

An element for which you do not have a matching template is processed by the built-in template:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and its child text nodes are copied to the output by:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```